# MySQL Optimization testing "WHERE (X=0 or X=1)" vs. "WHERE X<2"

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Is there a performance benefit to removing OR statements?

Which compiles faster

```
SELECT id FROM mytable where (x=0 or x=1)
```

or

```
SELECT id FROM mytable where x<2
```

I ran the test myself and the second one is a bit faster. BUT I am not sure if that is due to caching that happens when I run the first command. Is there a good way to evaluate two competing queries without them caching and affecting the others?

EXPLAIN produces the same output:

```
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | mytable | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1407715 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

Comment: You are right. The second one was fast because of caching. Can you just do explain for both the queries and paste the output here.

Comment: In your case both are same. as you have no index on x. Create an index on x and check, If you have no negetive values for x both should result into same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SQL_NO_CACHE :

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id FROM mytable where x<2
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you could get a fairly decent comparison by ensuring you stop and start the DBMS before each query. It may even be worthwhile shutting down the whole PC between runs.

Another possibility is to alternate a larger number of samples. Run the two queries `A` and `B` in the sequence `A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B,A,B` and average the results.

Also (although I don't *know* this about MySQL) most DBMS' have a query explainer which you should be using to check this sort of thing.

Those two queries *aren't* the same if `id` can go negative, by the way.

---

Based on your update, the EXPLAIN output, you get the same result for both queries. That means there should be no difference between them, all other things being equal.

However, since there's no mention of a key or index being used (or usable), you almost certainly don't have an index on `x`. If you add that, you should find that the query will be faster (this still depends on the cardinality of `x` but, as a general rule, it should improve).

Comment: There are caches at different levels, os, RAID (if any). So only fresh reboot can give you correct answer using that method, best is to use explain.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most basic way to evaluate a query is to take a look at its execution with [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html).

You can also take a look at [profiling](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-profiles.html), although it's nowhere as useful in most cases and it's more situational.

---

As it turns out, EXPLAIN shows that your query doesn't use any index (the "possible keys" column says "NULL" which is the fancy way to say there's nothing.) In your case, adding an index of the column `x` would drastically effect its execution.

Answer (score 1):

When you did your test, did you run the query one time or a thousand time ? Because the time for one run isn't relevant at all. You can also use [query explaining](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/explain.html) to help you decide.

Also, your second query as the problem to accept all values under 0, which can cause problems.

There's also another possibility :

```
SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE x BETWEEN 0 AND 1
```

It doesn't make a lot of sense when you have such a short interval, but can be used when the range is greater.

Performance wise, I really think **you shouldn't worry about this kind of optimization**, you'll gain nothing in the long run, this is not where your DBMS will lose his time. I really don't think this is worst benchmarking, just use the syntax you're the more comfortable with.